# Bootstrap Modal Element Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use the modal when clicking on an image. The image is within a button.
I have copied the code from the Bootstrap website but nothing is working. I have linked bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.js at the beginning of my html document.
Please help!

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> 
        <h4>SHORT SLEEVED SHIRT<br><br>$20</h4>
        <img src="images/femaleshortsleeved.jpg">
      </button>
      <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you also added jQuery?

Comment: No haha, is there a specific bootstrap jquery file? Or do I add my own?

Comment: Oh yeah! No I haven't, I'll give it a go

Comment: That hasn't worked, but there is nothing using javascript/jquery in the code above even though Bootstrap says it's toggling a modal via Javascript.

Comment: Check the browser console for other errors

Comment: I added jsFiddle as well ... hope mine and @DavidG answers help you on the way.

Comment: You should mark @DavidG answer as correct.

Comment: @Termato Thanks, but I wouldn't worry about it. User hasn't been seen since November :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included), you need to include jQuery.

> **jQuery required**
>
> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included, as shown in the starter template

Also note that you need to include it *before* the Bootstrap Javascript file.

Here is an example of your code working:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <h4>SHORT SLEEVED SHIRT<br><br>$20</h4>
    <img src="images/femaleshortsleeved.jpg">
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```